# How to a show message only once?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm making a minigame map where I want to show a text saying "Hi You Joined Seeker" when a player teleports to a set coordinate. I tried doing `/testfor @a/@p[1,2,3,1]`, but it started saying that to every player that comes near the radius (so players get the same message twice and thrice). Is there any command that can help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Try these commands, on a repeating command block and a chain command block, in order:

```
/tell @a[1,2,3,1,tag=!seeker] Hi you joined 'Seeker'
/scoreboard players tag add @a[1,2,3,1,tag=!seeker] seeker
```

When they teleport out, also run this command:

```
/scoreboard players tag remove @p[1,2,3,1] seeker
```

Comment: Thx ash4fun your solving all my command block queries. I will surely add your name in my costom map